# exporting Typescript interface / vs-code complains, but tsc is fine

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

If writing this in a create-react-app project then VS-Code complains about the last line `export { MyInterface}`

```
// test.ts

interface MyInterface {
  bazz(): void;
}

export { MyInterface }
```

This Error apears only in VS-Code - the typescript-compiler is fine

```
 Re-exporting a type when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided 
 requires using 'export type'.ts(1205)
 -----------------------------
 (alias) interface MyInterface
 export MyInterface
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue; note that "does not work" isn't sufficient.  Are you seeing some error?  [If so, I can't reproduce it](https://tsplay.dev/wQeljw).  If not, what exactly isn't working?

Comment: It is possible to do what you proposed.

Comment: Not only is it possible, what you claim does not work, in fact, works without modification. https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-stallman-yoxri?file=/src/index.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you everything.

> Re-exporting a type when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided
> requires using 'export type'.ts(1205)

If you have that compiler flag enabled, then you just need to change `export` to `export type` and works as you expect:

```
export type { MyInterface };
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-stallman-yoxri?file=/src/my-interface.ts:43-71)

---

According to [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#isolatedModules):

> Setting the `isolatedModules` flag tells TypeScript to warn you if you write certain code that can’t be correctly interpreted by a single-file transpilation process.
>
> It does not change the behavior of your code, or otherwise change the behavior of TypeScript’s checking and emitting process.

This flag forces you to be more explicit about exports. So you just have to tell typescript this export is for sure not meant to exist at runtime via `export type`.